# Returning row # in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, row

```
=ROWS($B$1:XLOOKUP(P18,B:B,B:B))
```

This returns the row number where column B matches the amount in P18.

P18=194.42

```
In column B:
Row#4 = 194.42
Row#7 = 194.42
```

Since 2 rows in column B are 194.42 this is returning the earliest row #4 when I need it to return the last row #7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `xlookup search_mode` ***-1 is to search from the last entry to the first***

```
XLOOKUP(P18,B:B,B:B,,,-1)
```